# .net core 2.1 - AddJsonOptions not working

Tags: .net-core, json.net

In my .net core 2.1 web app(WebApi + SPA) I am having problems with the API not correctly handling JSON:

- It is not camel-casing return values
- I'm getting the **JsonSerializationException: Self referencing loop detected for property** error

My startup.cs > configureservices looks like:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppContext");
            services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql().AddDbContext<AppContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(connectionString));

            services.AddScoped<ISCTMRepository, SCTMRepository>();

            services.AddMvc()
                .AddJsonOptions(options =>
                {
                    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
                    options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
                });

            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
            });
        }
```

I've tried updating my controller action to the following:

```
[HttpGet, Route("")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetLocations()
{
    var _data = await _repo.GetLocations();

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_data, 
            new JsonSerializerSettings {
                ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
                ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
            });
    return Ok(json);
}
```

And this does indeed fix both issues - but I'm not able to figure out why the global setting in startup is being ignored.

Answer (score 4):

It is because the serialization is not done by the framework, it is done by the call `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`, which does not respect the configuration you specify in Startup.cs - it does respect the `JsonSerializerSettings` you pass as a parameter.

If you write the API like this, you can see the configuration in Startup.cs takes effect.

```
[HttpGet, Route("")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetLocations()
{
    var _data = await _repo.GetLocations();
    return new OkObjectResult(_data);  //Let the framework serialize this object 
}
```

By the way, ASP.NET Core is by default using camel-casing in serialization, you don't really need to configure it explicitly. Just replace the line `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`.

Comment: Thanks for that. Makes sense - Implementing the return as you stated here, how do you specify your return status code? I've always used the IAction result which lets me easily return an OK or BadReqest etc.

Comment: Please check OkObjectResult class. See my updated answer.